# Set tab movement using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tags, focus

How does tabIndex work? Some of the controls get skipped while using tab. Is there a way to set focus or tab on a particular control using javascript? How can we set tab to go from one control to another?

I am new to web development. Please help out.

Comment: could you show us the code?

Comment: you should do a web search to find out `how tabindex works` before asking here